# Drupal 7. Custom pages for displaying data

Tags: 7

I'm juststarted with drupal and i want to create module for managing data in my custom database tables.
For example, i need to have three pages:
1) list of my subscribers 
2) editing subscriber 
3) adding subscriber

so, i need three pages for this:
**/subscribers

/subscriber/edit/id

/subscribers/add**

the question is: 
do i need to create three Basic pages with such aliases in admin 
and use specific templates files for each page to manage data?
or how to do it properly?

Comment: Drupal already provides add/edit functionality for content, is there a specific reason for overriding that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [hook_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) should get you the the ability to create those three pages.  Then you can use the page_callback to display the data you are looking to show. For the subscribers/id, you can use %id and then have pass the argument to the page_callback.  Using the db_query(), db_update(), db_select() functions in drupal, you'll be able to add the custom processing of the database.

If you are creating your own module you can use theme functions to decide how the page and that data will display.